# Look for highest value in a row and copy in excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to search for the highest value in a row and copy specific cells, from the column (based on row with highest value) into a different sheet. The scipt was working fine, but recently it has not been selecting the highest value, and I can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub DailyBH()
    Dim dailySht As Worksheet 'worksheet storing latest store activity
    Dim recordSht As Worksheet 'worksheet to store the highest period of each day
    Dim lColDaily As Integer ' Last column of data in the store activity sheet
    Dim lCol As Integer ' Last column of data in the record sheet
    Dim maxCustomerRng2 As Range ' Cell containing the highest number of customers
    Dim maxCustomerCnt As Double ' value of highest customer count


Set dailySht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("hourly KPI")
Set recordSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("@BH KPI")
With recordSht
    lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With


With dailySht
    lColDaily = .Cells(59, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    maxCustomerCnt = Round(Application.Max(.Range(.Cells(59, 1), .Cells(59, lColDaily))), 2)

     If Not maxCustomerRng2 Is Nothing Then

            .Cells(32, maxCustomerRng2.Column).Copy
            recordSht.Cells(32, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            recordSht.Cells(32, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats


            .Cells(14, maxCustomerRng2.Column).Copy
            recordSht.Cells(14, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            recordSht.Cells(14, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

            .Cells(59, maxCustomerRng2.Column).Copy
            recordSht.Cells(59, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            recordSht.Cells(59, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

End If
End With

 Set maxCustomerRng = Nothing
   Set dailySht = Nothing
   Set recordSht = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You have not set `maxCustomerRng2` so then it would be nothing.`If Not maxCustomerRng2 Is Nothing Then`

Comment: Yep, because it is nothing, you have not set `maxCustomerRng2` before the line `If Not maxCustomerRng2 Is Nothing Then` so that means it is nothing and skips over the line

Comment: @Davesexcel You're right. I've added the line Set maxCustomerRng2 = .Range(.Cells(39, 1), .Cells(39, lColDaily)).Find(What:=maxCustomerCnt, LookIn:=xlValues) but no value is copied.

Comment: seems that you are looking for the rounded value...perhaps that's the issue. Based on your comment above

Comment: @aab, in your comment you wrote `...Cells(39, 1), .Cells(39, lColDaily))….` while in your question code you have `...(.Range(.Cells(59, 1), .Cells(59, lColDaily…` -> you have to  use the _same_ column index in both expressions!